# Converting a list of "pairs" into a dictionary of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-itertools

This question was previously asked here with an egregious typo: [Counting "unique pairs" of numbers into a python dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52195887/counting-unique-pairs-of-numbers-into-a-python-dictionary)

This is an algorithmic problem, and I don't know of the most efficient solution. My idea would be to somehow cache values in a list and enumerate pairs...but that would be so slow. I'm guessing there's something useful from `itertools`.

Let's say I have a list of integers whereby are never repeats:

```
list1 = [2, 3]
```

In this case, there is a unique pair 2-3 and 3-2, so the dictionary should be:

```
{2:{3: 1}, 3:{2: 1}}
```

That is, there is 1 pair of 2-3 and 1 pair of 3-2.

For larger lists, the pairing is the same, e.g.

```
list2 = [2, 3, 4]
```

has the dicitonary

```
{2:{3:1, 4:1}, 3:{2:1, 4:1}, 4:{3:1, 2:1}}
```

(1) Once the size of the lists become far larger, how would one algorithmically find the "unique pairs" in this format using python data structures?

(2) I mentioned that the lists cannot have repeat integers, e.g.

```
[2, 2, 3]
```

is impossible, as there are two 2s.

However, one may have a list of lists:

```
list3 = [[2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

whereby the dictionary must be

```
{2:{3:2, 4:1}, 3:{2:2, 4:1}, 4:{2:1, 3:1}}
```

as there are two pairs of 2-3 and 3-2. How would one "update" the dictionary given multiple lists within a list?

EDIT: My ultimate use case is, I want to iterate through hundreds of lists of integers, and create a single dictionary with the "counts" of pairs. Does this make sense? There might be another data structure which is more useful.

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys in a dictionary, so your desired results aren't going to happen.

Comment: @DSM I understand; let me edit

Comment: keys in the dictionary are unique

Comment: You might get sth like: `{2:{3: 2, 4: 1}, 3:{2: 2, 4: 1}, 4:{3: 1, 2: 1}}` which would make more sense.

Comment: @DSM I have edited the question; Apologies, I wasn't thinking clearly

Comment: @schwobaseggl This is correct; see edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the nested list example, you can do the following, making use of `itertools.permutations` and `dict.setdefault`:

```
from itertools import permutations

list3 = [[2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]

d = {}
for l in list3:
    for a, b in permutations(l, 2):
        d[a][b] = d.setdefault(a, {}).setdefault(b, 0) + 1

# {2: {3: 2, 4: 1}, 3: {2: 2, 4: 1}, 4: {2: 1, 3: 1}}
```

For flat lists `l`, use only the inner loop and omit the outer one

Comment: this is simply beautiful +1. For flat lists one can nest them to leave the code intact. like `lst = [lst] if not isinstance(lst[0], list) else lst`.

Answer (score 1):

For this example I'll just use a list with straight numbers and no nested list:

```
values = [3, 2, 4]
result = dict.from_keys(values)
for key, value in result.items():
    value = {}
    for num in values:
        if num != key:
            value[num] = 1
```

This creates a dict with each number as a key. Now in each key, make the value a nested dict who's contents are `num: 1` for each number in the original values list if it isn't the name of the key that we're in

Answer (score 1):

use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with [permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import permutations

d = defaultdict(dict)
for i in [x for x in permutations([4,2,3])]:
    d[i[0]] = {k: 1 for k in i[1:]}
```

output is

```
In [22]: d
Out[22]: defaultdict(dict, {2: {3: 1, 4: 1}, 4: {2: 1, 3: 1}, 3: {2: 1, 4: 1}})
```

for inherit list of lists https://stackoverflow.com/a/52206554/8060120

Comment: what is the reason for the set?

Comment: it is dict `k: 1`

Comment: I am talking about the `{x for x in permutations([4,2,3])}`

Comment: Also the `defaultdict` has to be initialized somewhere.You are probably missing a line

Comment: thank you for default, and you are roght the set is overrcoding while i search the solution.